# Adding scrollbars to UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, scrollbar

I am trying to add vertical and horizontal scrollbars to my UserControl with the HorizontalScroll and VerticalScroll properties, but I am having extreme issues. My problem arises when I drag or manipulate the scroll box on the bar. When I let it go, it simply jumps back to the start position!

I know of the AutoScroll property, but I do not want to use it since I want to be able to control every aspect of my scrollbars, and I don't want it to be done automatically. Also, according to the documentation, AutoScroll is for "[enabling] the user to scroll to any controls placed outside of its visible boundaries" which isn't what I want. I just want scrollbars.

...aaand I suppose I could add VScrollBar and HScrollBar to the control, but why should I do this when the scroll functionality already exists? Seems like a waste to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the AutoScrollMinSize property.

If you implemented the OnPaint() override then you'll need to use the AutoScrollPosition property to set the arguments for [e.Graphics.TranslateTransform()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.translatetransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).